# empty column in pdf version of ssrs report

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

My report structure:

- header
- tablix in rectangle
- footer

from reportviewer and visual studio all looks great, but when i render pdf i'm getting document consisting of 3 pages, first (with header) is ok, but the rest gets an empty column on the right

i try to put each column and row in rectangle etc.
i'm sure that size of my report body is ok (body + margins <= page)

example with colors (dark blue - subreport in rectangle, yellow - main container):
[image]

height is correct, but width from second page is too large

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is your issue, but I have found that I get that kind of issue when the width of report + left margin + right margin is too close to page size.  An easy way to see if this may be the issue is to see if you have random blank pages.  I would also suggest attempting to shorten the columns to all fit on one page width.  Another thing to try is export it to Word.  Strangely enough, if the report goes over the width that you specify for a page, Word will accommodate your report and become a bigger page size.  See if you are still missing columns in those cases.

Comment: thanks for the answer
i built my report all over again and it's work perfectly, but until now i don't know the cause of my previous problems

Comment: @Piotr Did you change the width of the report?  The only reason I ask, is because changing the size usually fixes that kind of issue for me.

Comment: @Piotr Well, that is disappointing.  But hey, at least it is working now for you.  Perhaps the report had a glitch?